MySQL 8.4 out of memory
We have an instance of MySQL 8.4 running on Windows Server 2022. It ran fine for 12 days, but suddenly it is consuming a lot of memory. I've deducted this from the Windows Event log and the MySQL error log.
Example: (MySQL error log) [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory (Needed 1594376 bytes) and (Windows event log) The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: mysqld.exe (2944) consumed 15530082304 bytes.
Here's the whole MySQL error log: https://pastebin.com/4pcwaDHJ
Anyone who can help me figure out what might be going on, and perhaps tell me if the my.ini-settings are completely wrong?
EDIT: I've run MySQLTuner for Windows, without finding any issue exept 533 joins performed without indexes.
Here's the my.ini-file: https://pastebin.com/4bSbM5Vz
The server is a VM with 24 GB RAM and runs Wordpress (PHP) under IIS. Runs between 5 and 30 sites (WP and some also WooCommerce).
Thanks in advance.
-Espen.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to determine MySQL pre-allocated memory footprint?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the suggestion, but the error log say "Most likely, you have hit a bug...", so I need to find out if this is the case, or if it's my settings.

"533 joins performed without indexes" -- in a single query?  Or 533 separate queries?

The quick fix is to lower innodb_buffer_pool_size.
A better fix is to add this plugin:WP Index Improvements
